# WCF: How to create a method that will allow me to pass in and operate on an array of proxies with various types?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I was wondering if anyone can come up with a way that I can set the ClientCredentials of all my proxies using a single method call. For example, if I have:

```
public class ServiceOneClient : ClientBase<IServiceOne>, IServiceOne
...

public class ServiceTwoClient : ClientBase<IServiceTwo>, IServiceTwo
...
```

how can I create a method that I can call like this?

```
SetProxyCredentials(serviceOneClient, serviceTwoClient);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure if its possible through an array since each proxy will have its own interface but maybe this would help :

```
public static void SetProxyCredential<T>(ClientBase<T> proxy) where T : class
{
  //set credential
}
```

you could then call `SetProxyCrendential<IMyInterface>(proxy);`